# php json_encode utf8 char problem ( mysql )

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, json

I am writing to the database in the form of data from a form with jQuery [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode).

However, data from the database will corrupt.

```
$db->query("SET NAMES utf8");

$kelime = array("Merhaba","Dünya");
$bilgi = json_encode($kelime);

$incelemeEkle = "
INSERT INTO incelemeRapor SET
bigData = '".$bilgi."'
";
$db->query($incelemeEkle);
```

Database Table Schema;

```
CREATE TABLE `incelemeRapor` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bigData` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

MySQL Inserted Example Data;

```
["Merhaba","Du00fcnya"]
```

Comment: What encoding is the actual PHP file saved as?

Comment: Based on the MySQL documentation the charset is encased in quotes when using SET NAMES, which, you do not seem to have so you might not be actually setting utf8.

Comment: @Jamie Taniguchi: nope, it can be used like this

Answer (score 26):

Always escape your data before puting it in a SQL query:

```
$incelemeEkle = "
INSERT INTO incelemeRapor SET
bigData = '".mysql_real_escape_string($bilgi)."'
";
```

(added `mysql_real_escape_string()` call)

`json_encode()` encodes non-ascii characters with the `\u<code-point>` notation; so `json_encode(array("Merhaba","Dünya"));` returns `["Merhaba","D\u00fcnya"]`.

Then this string is embeded in a SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO incelemeRapor SET
bigData = '["Merhaba","D\u00fcnya"]'
```

There is no special meaning for the escape sequence `\u`, so MySQL just removes the `\`; and this results in `["Merhaba","Du00fcnya"]` being stored in database.

So if you escape the string, the query becomes:

```
$incelemeEkle = "
INSERT INTO incelemeRapor SET
bigData = '["Merhaba","D\\u00fcnya"]'
";
```

And `["Merhaba","D\u00fcnya"]` is stored in the database.

Answer (score 2):

I tried with mysql_real_escape_string() but not worked for me (result to empty field in database).

So I looked here : http://php.net/manual/fr/json.constants.php and the flag **JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE** worked for me fine :

```
$json_data = json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

*JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE is available only since PHP 5.4.0 !*

Answer (score 1):

So in addition to ensuring that your database is using utf8_unicode_ci, you also want to make sure PHP is using the proper encoding.  Typically I run the following two commands at the top of any function which is going to potentially have foreign characters within them.  Even better is to run it as one of the first commands when your app starts:

```
mb_language('uni');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

Those two lines have saved me a ton of headaches!

Answer (score 0):

Like user576875 says, you just need to correctly treat your string before inserting it into the database.  `mysql_real_escape_string()` is one way to do that.  Prepared statements are another way.  This will also save you from the SQL injection security issue that you might be susceptible to if you write user input directly into SQL.  Always use one of the above two methods.

Also, note that this has little to do with UTF8.  JSON is ASCII safe, so as long as you use an ASCII like character set (utf8, iso-8859-1), the data will be inserted and stored correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I would apply BASE64 encoding to the JSON string. This should work with nearly every php setting, database, database version and setting:

```
$values = array("Test" => 1, "the" => 2, "West" => 3);
$encoded = base64_encode(json_encode($values));
$decoded = json_decode(base64_decode($encoded), true);
```

Comment: you don't need to base64 encode JSON.  It's ASCII safe.  Only 7 bit characters.

Comment: You're right. But base64 encoding avoids any problems with backslashes (or other special chars)